# Xubuntu 20.10: "cowsay" script

Tags: scripts, xubuntu

Im trying to make a "cowsay" script but i need to know how to do if equal this or that and how to make it accept input (in a sh script file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash `read` reads a line from standard input (stdin).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Do we have any arguments?
if ((!$#)); then
    read -r -p "Input an animal: " input
else
    input="$1"
fi
case "$input" in
    cat)
        echo its a $input
    ;;
    cow)
        echo The $input says moo
    ;; 
    *)
        echo This is not an animal\!
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: yeah but i need it to do a certain thing like: If response=blah then do blah

Comment: question: is $ a variable? cause if so im gonna add one

Comment: You assign a variable with `varname="string of words"` and use the variable with $varname e.g. `echo "$varname"` ($REPLY is a default variable read uses)

Comment: does "case $"var" in" set the input variable orrrrrrr...

Comment: `case` just reads a "word" in this case the content of $REPLY, you could e.g. read an argument instead, it would look something like `case "$1" in` and you run the script `./script.sh cow`

Answer (score 0):

I modified your script a bit bc I want to enter the animal than the phrase:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "Enter Animal/Creature And Phrase: "
case "$REPLY" in
        cowsay -f $REPLY
    ;;
    
esac
```